# Issues after enabling state country pick list

Tags: country-and-state

We have implemented state/ country pick list after converting data. 
The issue is one  class is shown in the customizations list which i need to update.

i have below line in this class which is causing the issue

```
acc=[select name,id,billingStateCode  from account where id=:recid  limit 1];
```

When i comment out this line i don't see this class in the customizations i need to update.

My question is which field should i reference in the soql?

Answer (score 1):

The search for customizations to update assumes that you haven't made any updates yet, so it's seeing that the SOQL query contains the string "billingState" and assuming that it's a reference to the old text billingState field that should be updated to the new billingStateCode picklist field.

If you're already using billingStateCode, you should be fine.